# Is it possible to choose a specific form to be serialized with Syphon?

Tags: backbone.js

[Syphon](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon)'s `serialize` method receives a view and a set of options as parameter. If that view has several forms, it will scan it and serialize the *first* form it finds. But I have a view with several forms and I'd like to choose the specific form it should serialize. Is that possible with Syphon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using jQuery is pretty simple:

```
Backbone.Syphon.serialize($("#form_id")[0]);
```

Comment: This does not work, at least not with later versions of backbone.syphon; I get a "can't find $el" message.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you. It could be `$("#form_id").get(0)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I could find a way around Syphon, using Underscore.js:

```
 var serializeForm = function(el) {
    var result = {};
    _.each($(el).serializeArray(), function(e){
      if (e.value) result[e.name] = e.value
    });
    return result;
  }
```

This function will generate a javascript object based on the form fields. Only fields with values will be included in the result.